# Generating SOAP Action Header on Wcf-Custom Send Port

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, soap, biztalk

I am in the process of creating a Send Port in Biztalk, that uses the Wcf-Custom adapter for sending SOAP requests.

So far I have been testing the SOAP requests in Visual Studio, using C# code from the System-ServiceModel namespace. See code below:

```
/ CODEGEN: Generating message contract since the operation transferPayments is neither RPC nor document wrapped.
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="urn:CorporateService:transferPayment", ReplyAction="*")]
    [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute()]
    transferPaymentsResponse transferPayments(transferPayment1 request);

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="urn:CorporateService:transferPayment", ReplyAction="*")]
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<transferPaymentsResponse> transferPaymentsAsync(transferPayment1 request);
```

I need to add this "transferPayment" action to the SOAP Action Header field in the adapter.

[image]

Using the provided example, I've come up with this

```
<BtsActionMapping xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">  
<Operation Name="TransferPayment" Action="http://bankconnect.dk/schema/2014/CorporateService/TransferPayment" />  
</BtsActionMapping>
```

Where "http://bankconnect.dk/schema/2014" is the namespace, "CorporateService" is the service, and "TransferPayment" is the action. I'm unsure if this is the correct way to go about implementing this.

My question how I should format the SOAP Action Headers, so that they correspond to the c# code used.

Comment: See if following webpage helps : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/How-to-add-custom-5cbbf066

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you use the `BizTalk WCF Service Consume Wizard` to generate the schema's inside BizTalk. This would make all the possible Actions for you.